# Simply description restrict keyword

Tags: c

- I'm a junior C programmer.I don't understand the ***restrict*** keyword.Can
  you simply explain?Thanks for help.

Comment: `* restrict p`: Access to data pointed by `p` only occurs because of `p` or values derived from `p`.  Is that simply enough?

Comment: If you can access this site then you can also access Google.

Answer (score 0):

The restrict keyword basically says the pointer is not overlapping with the other one (you need to have 2 pointers for this to work), that way the compiler can skip some checks and optimize your code better.

Comment: Do not need 2 pointers although that is certainly one way to see the usefulness of `restrict`.